# How to load images depending on browser width

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <img id="demo" src="" />    

<script>
    if (window.innerWidth > 500)
    {

    }
    else 
    {

    }
</script>
```

This is my code. How to change the value of src depending on the browser width?

Comment: did you tried this code? try and check first.Also what are the two src will be there in your question? can you add them?

Comment: You can use percentage <img id="demo" src="" width="50%" /> or this js to change width: document.getElementById("demo").width = (window.innerWidth / 2) + "px";

Comment: You can use this to change source value document.getElementById("demo").src="../template/save.png";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to change source value:

```
<img id="demo" src="" />    

<script>
var img = document.getElementById("demo");
    if (window.innerWidth > 500)
    {
    img.src="your source";
    }
    else 
    {
    img.src="your source";
    }
</script>
```

or

```
$('#demo').src="your path";
```

if you use the JQuery library use this:

```
$("#demo").attr('src', '//srcImage.jpg or any path');
```

Answer (score 1):

Generaly, you can switch image using media query and CSS but if you realy need JS, you can do something like this:

```
 <script>
    var resize_image = function(event) {
        var img = document.getElementById("demo");
        var w = window.innerWidth;

        if(w < 2000)
        {
            img.src = 'LINK1';
        }
        else if(w < 1024)
        {
            img.src = 'LINK2';
        }
        else if(w < 992)
        {
            img.src = 'LINK3';
        }
        else if(w < 768)
        {
            img.src = 'LINK4';
        }
        else
        {
            img.src = 'LINK5';
        }
    };
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', resize_image); // document loaded
    window.addEventListener('resize', resize_image, true); // on resize
</script>
```

But if you need responsive image, just give your image simple CSS rules like:

```
#demo{
display:block;
max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean getElementById not getElementByID:)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to resolve this problem using CSS then you can Use CSS Media query.
You can change the image according to media query with JQuery. I think you got my point of view.